# How to parse link texts to html in React

Tags: html, reactjs, react-component

Hi I have the following data returned from an API service as social media handles. I console.log the returned data and got the following.

> 0: {type: 'facebook', handle: 'www.facebook.com/username'}
> 1: {type: 'twitter', handle: 'www.twitter.com/username'}
> length: 2
> [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

I need it to be represented on the web page as a normal html link with the social media icons showing as follows:

```
<a href="www.facebook.com/username"><i className="bi bi-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="www.twitter.com/username"><i className="bi bi-twitter"></i></a>
```

I have tried the following

```
const socialMediaLinks=socialMediaHandles.map(handle => `<a href='${handle.handle}'>
<i className='bi-bi-${handle.type}'></i></a>`)
```

I then go to where I want it to display on the component and paste the following code

```
{socialMediaLinks}
```

but when I do that, the text is returned just as text and not rendered as html on the page.

I am using React functional component.

I am actually new to React and trying to figure out how to achieve this. I will appreciate any guide.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are ways to inject strings of HTML into a React application, they are error prone and dangerous.

Don't generate strings of HTML.

You're using JSX already, use JSX there too.

```
const socialMediaLinks=socialMediaHandles.map(handle => (
    <a href={handle.handle}>
        <i className={`bi-bi-${handle.type}`}></i>
    </a>
));
```

Comment: This worked perfectly the moment I used it. But all of a sudden it started showing "socialMediaHandles.map is not a function" and I never changed that variable. Any ideas as to what could be responsible please?

Comment: There's no way to tell how you changed the value of `socialMediaHandles` from the code you've provided. You could ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Don't forget to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a condition to ensure that the returned variable is an array before trying to map through it as follows 

Array.isArray(socialMediaHandles)?socialMediaHandles.map(handle => (
                    <a href={`https://${handle.handle}`}>
                        <i className={`bi bi-${handle.type}`}></i>
                    </a>
                    )):"No social media handles to display"